# Linq conflict error

Tags: asp.net, linq, c#-4.0, conflict

I keep getting these on my website, visitors reporting them fairly regularly as well.  Refreshing the page always fixes it.  Here is an email report I got from the server for a typical one:

> Error in: http://www.scirra.com/ReleaseView.aspx?rtitle=r49 Error
>   Message: Row not found or changed. Stack Trace: at
>   System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode
>   failureMode)  at
>   System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode) 
>   at LoggedInUser..ctor()  at MasterPages_Main.Page_Init(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) at
>   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object
>   o, Object t, EventArgs e)  at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)  at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)  at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

It's not giving a line number or anything else much useful.  The page in question isn't doing anything complex at all.

Any ideas?  It's not an error I've managed to reproduce, it just keeps happening regularly.

Comment: Could it be a concurrency issue?  Can you post the code that the error is originating from?

Comment: Is there any updating happening on this page/request on the visit? Either by the page, or trigger perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suspect your LINQ To SQL .dbml is out of sync with your database. Either the model is old, or the production database isn't the same as when the .dbml was created. Were any columns modified? Perhaps a column has had its nullable status changed?

Try deleting and adding that table in question from your .dbml design surface. Unsure if you've got multiple environments(dev/test/prod), but do this .dbml change against the production database, and redeploy your application.

Perhaps double check that your table and the dbml entity match as you expect, property by property on the nullable attributes. [Another problem showing the same symptom](http://forums.asp.net/t/1232064.aspx). Also consider any DateTime columns and whether you can set those columns/properties to "Never" for concurrency checks.

Comment: I'm 99% sure that it's all syncd fine but will recreate it anyway, can this really be the cause even if refreshing the page seems to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me that the row your are trying to update is out-of-date (the current row in the database does not match the row as you got it from the database). the default for 'Conflictmode failureMode' is to raise an exception in case of a conflict. See [this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345081.aspx#Y134).

You should examine why you end up with out of date data in those rows. It got changed by something or someone else. Are you caching the data? Are you running in a webfarm? ....
I think that [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.memberchangeconflict.aspx) describes how you could deal with it.

Comment: Thanks, no caching and no webfarm, could this be caused by the same record being updated concurrently?

Comment: I edited the answer with a better link. That also shows how you can detect what got changed. I don't do linq to sql much so I'm not sure how in reads/caches rows from the database. In order for this to get out of sync you need to read the same row into 2 different objects then edit/save the first and after that save the second.

Comment: Ahh and another way could be if another program/sql job/whatever code modifies the database from outside of your webapp